# "mercurial-server: access denied" using ssh style URL

Tags: mercurial

I'm trying to user mercurial-server on a Raspberry Pi (conveniently at my desk before I ask the sysadmins to install on Ubuntu server). The Pi is running Raspbian Buster (recent update/upgrade routine). The ultimate goal is a set of repos for students such that they can't peek at each others' code, but I can clone any student's work for grading.

I have a small Mercurial repo testproject in my home directory. My id_rsa.pub key is in `~hg/.ssh/authorized_keys` after running the Mercurial server `refresh-auth` script. In the log files I can see that my public key exchange worked. Everything in `/var/lib/mercurial-server/` seems to be owned hg:hg, and the permissions look reasonable. I'm running from localhost to localhost so it's the same version of hg that's running at both ends. I can `sudo -u hg hg init louis/testproject` in hg's home directory and it creates the repo no problem (I deleted it before retrying from ssh).

```
$ cd testproject
$ hg clone -v --debug . ssh://hg@localhost/louis/testproject
```

What I get is:

```
running ssh 'hg@localhost' 'hg init louis/testproject'
mercurial-server: access denied
abort: could not create remote repo!
```

I also tried from Windows 10 (x64) with TortoiseHG. It starts working then just stalls, needing the Task Manager to kill the TortoiseHG workbench. I stopped trying that to remove complexity.

I'm hoping the problem is not the Pi, but I suppose I can always get a DO droplet running Ubuntu.

As always, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Oh never mind... The access.conf file was incorrect.